# Select Tag inside element by id and check it's class - prototype

Tags: prototypejs

I am trying to check if tag a have id `selected`.
I have html:

```
    <div id="30-super-attribute-138" class="colorswatch-lines">
        <a class="lnk-colorswatch selected" id="30-lnk-colorswatch-138-34" href="javascript:selectColorSwatch(138, 34, 30, true)"></a>
    </div>
```

and my prototype script:

```
    if ($('30-super-attribute-138 a').hasClassName('selected')) {
        var myStyle = '#333';
        $('main-picture').setStyle ({
          backgroundColor: myStyle 
        });
    }
```

setStyle is working as expected, but I have troubles to check, if tag `a` have class selected - it happened, after selecting a colour.
In console I see error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClassName' of null`

Please, how to correctly select tag a from inside div with id `30-super-attribute-138`

Thank you Peter

Answer (score 1):

...hmmm that was easy, to get first child element with prototype:

```
if ($('30-super-attribute-138').down('a').hasClassName('selected')) {
    var myStyle = '#333';
    $('main-picture').setStyle ({
      backgroundColor: myStyle 
    });
}
```

OK, now it looks very simple sorry for this kind of question.

Comment: ...I modify `.down('a').hasClassName('selected')` to `.down('a.selected')`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an alternative way of doing it in PrototypeJS that you might find helpful/interesting, this could work in a single DOM call:

```
if($$('#30-super-attribute-138 a.selected')[0]) {
    var myStyle = '#333';
    $('main-picture').setStyle ({
        backgroundColor: myStyle 
    });
}
```

happy coding!